# How can I tell is integer one or two digit number?

Tags: javascript

How can I using JavaScript tell if the integer is one or two digit number?

I'm creating time filter in Angular and I need to add 0 in front of a number every time its only one digit. For example instead of 1:2:3 to have 01:01:03.

Comment: Well, have you tried it yourself yet?

Comment: `('0' + myInt).slice(-2)`

Comment: An integer can't have a leading zero, so you have to convert to string to add that, and to check if it needs the leading zero it's as easy as checking if the number is less than 10.

Comment: If you could possibly have negative values, you have to check less than 10 and greater than -10 or -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to a string first and if the length of that string is shorter than 2 add a 0 in front of it.
Example:

```
if (currentMinutes.toString().length == 1) {
    currentMinutes = "0" + currentMinutes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest check is to divide the number by 10, and add a leading zero if it's output is between 0 and 1.

```
var a = numberYouWant;
if(a/10 < 1 && a/10 > 0){
    a = "0" + String(a);
}
```